# Print out the time using currenttimemillis() function

Tags: java, eclipse, time

Any body can help with an idea why it does not print the time out? 
 when I try to load an image ?e.g how long it takes for an image to be loaded using    java eclipse..currenttimemillis()
     I would like to say a big thank you in advance

```
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
     import java.lang.reflect.Method;
     import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
     import java.util.Date;


 public class TracingInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

private Object target;
private PrintWriter out;
private Object obj;

public TracingInvocationHandler(Object target, PrintWriter out,Object obj) {
    this.target = target;
    this.out = out;
    this.obj = obj;

}

@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
        throws Throwable {
       long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object result = null;

        out.println("Image " + method.getName() + " (...) entered.");
        result = method.invoke(obj, args);
        out.println("Image " + method.getName() + " (...) returned.");

         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

         long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

          String strTotalTime = String.valueOf(totalTime);

          System.out.printf(" [%s] %s Image %s took %d ms:",new Date().toString(), method.getName(),args[0],strTotalTime);

         return result;

}

public static Object createProxy(Object target, PrintWriter out,Object obj) {
    Class<?> targetClass = target.getClass();
    ClassLoader currentClassLoader = targetClass.getClassLoader();
    Class<?>[] interfaces = targetClass.getInterfaces();
    InvocationHandler handler = new TracingInvocationHandler(target, out,obj);
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(currentClassLoader, interfaces, handler);
}

   public static Object newInstance(Object obj){   //create a new instance 
   ClassLoader loader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
    Class[] classes = obj.getClass().getInterfaces();
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        loader, classes, new TracingInvocationHandler(obj));
```

}

}

```
  error message: the constructor TracingInvocationHanlder(Object) is undefined
  error message at last line :  new TracingInvocationHandler(obj));
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

You never pass in the correct parameters for `TracingInvocationHandler`. Make sure you pass in full parameters such as:

```
new TracingInvocationHandler(obj, System.out, obj2);
```

A machine that uses water and rice to cook rice can't make cooked rice with just water.

Comment: error message:The constructor TracingInvocationHandler (Object,PrintStream,Object) is undefined // error still stays at the same line of code :( for some reason

Comment: @user2729154 Then pass in a PrintStream :)

Comment: What ever I am doing I still get the error message : PirntStream cannot be resolved to a variable.....I also include this line of code: private static final PrintWriter PrintStream = null; the error is still there ;)

Comment: Grr. PrintStream is a class, not a variable. You need an *instance* of PrintStream.

Comment: :(((((((((((( I still cannot fix :(((

Comment: @user2729154 I'm busy at the moment.